# Java package and/or file structure compiling issue

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

Good morning, everybody.

So, I'm trying to compile a very super-simple Java program by way of a package structure, in which I have two java files. My folder structure is:
Prac/Java/LL/people/src/coreservlets/
and the two files are PersonTest.java (which is the main one) and Person.java

### The PersonTest.java file goes as follows:

```
package coreservlets;

public class PersonTest {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person("Jane", "Smith");
}
}
```

---

### and Person.java goes as follows:

```
package coreservlets;

public class Person {
public String firstName, lastName;

public Person(String initialFirstName,
              String initialLastName) {
    this.firstName = initialFirstName;
    this.lastName = initialLastName;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return(firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```

}

---

And when I try to compile, it tells me that it can't find the symbol Person. I've checked multiple forum entries to check to make sure I'm doing package structure correctly, and I can't figure out what the problem is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you compiling? Please show the exact command you're using and what directory you're running it from

Comment: Initially, I was changing-directory to the "coreservlets" folder trying:
javac PersonTest.java
and now I'm changing-directory to the "people" folder trying:
javac src/coreservlets/PersonTest.java

and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the class path needs to be set for each command (javac and java):

Follow bellow Steps

```
instead of going to subpackage, compile Person.java from the top_level:

$javac -cp . Prac/Java/LL/people/src/coreservlets/Person.java

compile PersonTest.java in the same way:

$javac -cp . Prac/Java/LL/people/src/coreservlets/PersonTest.java

run the file using the class path also:

$java -cp . Prac/Java/LL/people/src/coreservlets/PersonTest
```

ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: The Person.java file compiles perfectly fine, but the PersonTest.java still says it's not finding the symbol "Person"

Comment: gives me this error:

kourosh@Anicetus:~/Prac/Java/LL/people$ javac src/coreservlets/PersonTest.java
src/coreservlets/PersonTest.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
  Person p = new Person("Jane", "Smith");
  ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class PersonTest
src/coreservlets/PersonTest.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
  Person p = new Person("Jane", "Smith");
                 ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class PersonTest
2 errors